# How to apply a hover selector to buttons on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

On a SharePoint page, I have implemented a table and within the table have put buttons, which are just images.  They work great and the links are working too. However, I would like to incorporate a hover element where the button changes color.  I'm pretty sure this is possible using Javascript and CSS, however, I'm not sure exactly where to implement the code snippets.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS but if you are using images then I think you will need a separate image for the hover.

```
img.button {background-image: 'normalimage.png'}
img.button:hover {background-image: 'hoverimage.png'}
```

You can also do the same thing with background colours.

Comment: Thanks Dave!  That looks good, where do I put the code snippet?

Comment: You can add it to the page itself or within a CEWP on a page, or if your solution is using a custom CSS file then add it there.